# How to install mantaflow in 2.9

Tags: add-on

I've been trying to install manta flow for blender 2.9 and am stumped I cant find any tutorials or anything and from what I can see you cant install the blender experimental branch with manta flow anymore?

Comment: Hello :). Mantaflow is a part of Blender since v. 2.82. Release notes are [here](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.82/Physics).

Comment: thanks just realixed im a moron lol thank you